# Unclear padding in LinearLayout, how to remove them?

Tags: java, android, padding

I don’t understand where the padding in these three rectangles comes from. I need to remove them...
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6UcL3.jpg)

I paste these blocks as fragments

MainActivity.java

```
private Set<AbstractFigure> setFiguresInView() {
        final Set<AbstractFigure> figuresInView = new HashSet<>();
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        for (Integer layout : figureLayouts) {
            int randomIndex = (int) (Math.random() * figures.length);
            AbstractFigure selectFigure = (randomIndex >= 0 && randomIndex < figures.length - 1) ?
                    figures[randomIndex].copy() : figures[figures.length - 1].copy();
            ft.replace(layout, selectFigure);
            findViewById(layout).setOnDragListener(getOnDragListener());
            figuresInView.add(selectFigure);
        }
        ft.commit();
        return figuresInView;
    }
```

And here are these files

activity_main.xml

```
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="30dp">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/figure_layout1"
                layout="@layout/figure_layout" />

            <include
                android:id="@+id/figure_layout2"
                layout="@layout/figure_layout" />

            <include
                android:id="@+id/figure_layout3"
                layout="@layout/figure_layout" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

figure_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/figure_background"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="0dp">

    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Help me please

I removed the indents, but nothing happened
`android:padding="0dp"`

Comment: can you please provide a working example, what does setFiguresInView does. In which view it adds the views.

Comment: This method is called when the button is clicked

Answer (score 0):

Delete this line of code from your LineerLayout from activity_main.xml :

```
android:layout_margin="10dp"
```

if this is works or not, please reply back from comments.

Answer (score 0):

In **figure_layout.xml**, set height and width `wrap_content` to both ConstraintLayout and LinearLayout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/figure_background"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="0dp">

    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```